# Выделение потомка брата родителя без JS

Tags: вёрстка, css-selectors

```
                    Имеется некий html-код: 
                   <article class="news-article">
                        <header>
                            <a href="#"><img src="img/news-img1.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"></a>
                            <span class="date">12 Feb</span>
                        </header>
                        <div class="article-content">
                            <h3><a href="#">Amazing Image Post</a></h3>
                            <p>By <span class="author">admin</span><span class="separator">|</span><span class="comm-num">2</span> comment</p>
                        </div>
                    </article>
```

Можно ли без помощи JS при наведении на ссылку в блоке с классом .article-content подсветить span с классом .date в шапке статьи?

Comment: нельзя...........

Comment: Только костылем в стиле: расположить `<header>` после `div` но спозиционировать стилями выше.

Comment: Если отслеживать article:hover целиком

Answer (score 2):

CSS проходит по дереву тегов только сверху вниз и снаружи внутрь. Это часть идеологии, и, вероятно, она останется такой до конца жизни CSS как стандарта.

Поэтому для перехода к предкам, либо к соседям до текущего элемента - используйте js.